# Rails unable to debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, rubygems, rvm, rubymine

I have been messing with this issue for a very long time without any success. I just want to debug the application is either RubyMine or Aptana. Whenever I try to run the the application in debug mode I get the following exception

```
"/home/bsikander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require': cannot load such file -- debase (LoadError)
    from /home/bsikander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /home/bsikander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bsikander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `require_relative'
    from /home/bsikander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bsikander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    from /home/bsikander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'"
```

I searched on the internet regarding this and tried to install the debase gem but I get the following expception

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debase:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/bsikander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-2.0.0-p576 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I also installed the gem "debugger-ruby_core_source" but still not able to install debase or debug the application. Please help me or point me to the right direction.

My Ruby version is 2.0.0.

Comment: check the log file mentioned in the error, probably you're missing a library that's used to build the extension.

Comment: Where can i find that log file ? I am using ubuntu without rvm.

Comment: without? the output says `/home/bsikander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576` I'd suggest looking there, `find /home/bsikander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576 -name mkmf.log`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I mixed my other machine with the current one. I will look into the log file and will post it later today.

Comment: I ran your find command but there was no mkmf.log file.

Comment: ok so another suggestion, try installing `gem install ruby-debug-ide` instead, it worked with me before

Comment: OMG your solution worked. I installed gem ruby-debug-ide and it worked. I am pretty sure that I installed that before but whatever :) it works now. Thank you. You can post your answer below so that I can select it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I've switched from rvm to chruby, and I've got this same issue, after looking around and reading rubymine's error messages and stuff I tried installing `ruby-debug-ide` instead, and somehow it worked, so yea

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience using RubyMine and Aptana; I'd recommend checking out [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) or [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) as gem-based debugging tools for ruby, which in my experience have been easy to use and easy to get running.

I'd recommend byebug a little more highly, since pry isn't as specifically designed for debugging, and byebug's `next` command is a godsend at times.

Comment: byebug worked fine but it was console based. I somehow found a solution and everything is working fine in RubyMine now. Thank you.